# Windows - Find icon for MMC shortcut

Tags: shortcuts, icons, dll, mmc, windows-server-2016

I am trying to locate the DLL in which the icon for the Network Policy Server MMC shortcut is stored in. Typically for most shortcuts, you can just right-click on the shortcut, click the Change Icon button, and it will tell you. However, for Network Policy Server, it just tells me it is located in %SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll with an icon index of 0. This is clearly not accurate as this is the generic file icon.

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows is this?

Comment: Server 2016, although it would still be applicable to other versions due to Remote Server Administration Tools

Comment: I tried to find the shortcut last night but my investigations on Windows 10, Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2008 R2 didn't yield any results. So, I asked that.

Comment: Just FYR, the icon selection dialog **always** pops up with `shell32.dll` in the text box, regardless of which dll *actually* contains the icon. It is said that the dialog sometimes comes with `imageres.dll` but I've never observed it by myself.

Comment: @iBug you would be mistaken, at least on Server 2016. I havent had to do this in a long time so I cant comment on other versions of Windows. I had to do this for several MMCs which I am adding as RemoteApps to a Remote Desktop Services 2016 Session Host. All of them except the Network Policy Server displayed the correct DLL when I would click the Change Icon button, for example the Group Policy Management MMC - http://imgur.com/a/Zjs9J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the shortcut in a hex editor the path to the DLL can be found. Who knows why Windows isnt able to display it properly for this shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my system it is in %windir%\system32\mmcshext.dll

I did use https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html to find the dll.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way to locate the DLL is to go to the Administrative Tools and act like you are going to change the icon there. It will give you the dll that is referenced and you can then make note of it and change it on your newer shortcut.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).